# Forecast demand of customers on a special day of month

Tags: r

I’m struggling with forecasting the demand of the customers on a special day of the month. I have the daily data on the customers’ demand, weekend or not (0 and 1), first day of month or not (0 and 1), holiday or not (0 and 1). I used Arima models for forecasting and the result was ok with normal days of the month with very small difference between the real demand and the forecasted demand. However, on the first day of every month, due to the monthly promotion, the demand is significantly higher than that on other days. I tried to build a regression model as well. The prediction on the first day of month using regression was better than that using arima model. However, in general, R-squared was just 0.5 which is not high enough. Any one has any ideas which method I can use here to forecast the demand on the first day of the month most accurately? Many thanks!

Comment: And I am not sure whether my questions have had enough details or not. I am using R for the analysis. If there is any further information needed, please let me know :)

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're misinterpreting what the coefficient of determination (R-squared) value is measuring. Having an R-squared value of 0.5 is not necessarily a bad thing. Here's an excerpt that might clarify the definition of R-squared, from J. Scott Armstrong's *Long Range Forecasting from Crystal Ball to Computer* (1978), page 323:

> An R-squared of 0 means that the model is not useful in explaining fluctuations, but it does not reflect its ability to forecast levels; thus, R-squared = 0 may not be a completely bad forecast. Similarly, an R-squared of 1.0 does not represent a perfectly good forecast. Also, R-squared depends not only on the fit of the data but also on the steepness of the regression line, implying that R-squared will be higher when changes are greater.

Of course, adding additional variables to your regression will overfit your data and increase the R-squared value, without necessarily increasing your model's accuracy.

There are many methods to measure the predicative accuracy of a model, and which one is best depends on your specific situation. For example, measuring accuracy by Mean Absolute Percentage Error (MAPE) is useful when the cost of errors is more closely associated with the percentage error than with the unit error; if the opposite were true, then it would be more appropriate to select a model based on whichever has a lower Mean Absolute Deviation (MAD).

If I were tasked with selecting a forecasting model for your scenario, I would ignore the low R-squared value and decide what type of error would be most prudent to minimize, and then select the model that minimizes whatever error measurement that might be.

**Update:**

Note that it is possible that an MPE of 52% is a fundamental limit for your data set, given that you are trying to predict a numerical variable (customer demand) with only three binary variables; this would mean that no model would fair much better. However, if you'd like to try another model to see if you get better results (which you likely will), and you want to write a program in R, I would recommend taking a look at [this course website](http://analytics.shuaihuang.info/) for some examples of data analytics algorithms in R. Some models are very complicated and I realize that it's a lot of information to go through, so it might be easiest to start with a logistic regression model (if you haven't already done so) because the code for that is very similar to the code for a linear regression model.

Since you're taking in a few binary or categorical variables, I think a decision tree would be the best model for your data set. It is easy to interpret and can be coded with only a few lines in R. [This R markdown file](http://analytics.shuaihuang.info/resource/r/Essential_decision_tree.Rmd) from the same course website linked above gives an example of coding a decision tree for a regression model starting on line 72.

Comment: Thank you very much Randy for your help. I will try the method you advised and hopefully it will work for me :)

Comment: Hi randy, I've just tried to measure the predicative accuracy of my regression model and got the MPE of 52% which does not look good to me :( Do you have any other recommendation for a model that can predict accurately on both normal days and first day of month? Thanks a lot!

Comment: It's very kind of you providing me such a lot of help and information. I will try to figure it out with logistic regression model and a decision tree as well. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Have you already tried a regression tree? There are several implementations of it, e.g. M5P provided by the RWeka package? Assuming the data is in a data frame called `myData` and the dependent variable `myData$demands`, you could use this predictor as follows:

```
# Load the library with M5-prime.
library(RWeka)

# Create the model.
modelM5P <- M5P(demands ~ ., data = myData)

# Explore the model.
summary(modelM5P)
```

The last line will show you the summary of the model. It will look something like that:

```
=== Summary ===

Correlation coefficient                 0.9441
Mean absolute error                     16500.5686
Root mean squared error                 26462.9886
Relative absolute error                 28.112  %
```

You can then test the model on the train data and measure in performance.

```
# Perform prediction on the test data set.
# Exclude the dependent variable (assumable column 4) 
# from the prediction data.
prediction <- predict(modelM5P, myData[, -4])
```

`prediction` will now contain the predicted demand. Next you could study it for the accuracy against the train data.